# Can status method from Svn::Client::Context return an array

Tags: ruby, svn

I'm trying to use ruby's SVN bindings to get the commit date of a file. The below code works. However, I'm not content with the fact that I need to use a block to get the results from the status method. Is there a better way ?

```
ctx = Svn::Client::Context.new()
ctx.add_simple_prompt_provider(2) do |cred, realm, user_name, may_save|
  cred.username = "sorin"
  cred.password = "realyniftypassword"
end

svndate = nil
ctx.status(path, "HEAD", true, true) do |path, status| 
    break if status.entry.nil?
    svndate = status.entry.cmt_date
end 

next if svndate.nil?
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
svndate = ctx.status(path, "HEAD", true, true)[0].entry.cmt_date
```

but ctx.status returns a integer.

Is there a more appropriate method ?

I use the Ubuntu deb package libsvn-ruby1.8, and I could not find any documentation on it except a few examples on the net.

Comment: Which binding are you using? Do you have a link to the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, there is a Ruby gem which may help.

http://rubygems.org/gems/svn_wc
https://github.com/dvwright/svn_wc/

```
require 'svn_wc'
conf = {
  "svn_repo_master"       => "svn+ssh://sorin@192.168.10.1/opt/repo",
  "svn_user"              => "sorin",
  "svn_pass"              => "realyniftypassword",
  "svn_repo_working_copy" => "/tmp/local_working_repo/root",
  #"svn_repo_config_path"  => "/tmp/my_config"
}

svn = SvnWc::RepoAccess.new YAML::dump(conf)
repo_wc = conf['svn_repo_working_copy']
svn.list_entries(repo_wc, nil, verbose=true).each do |info|
  puts "#{info[:entry_name]} #{info[:cmt_date]}"
end
```

Comment: Hmmm, well based on these two questions:
"I'm trying to use ruby's SVN bindings to get the commit date of a file,..."
and
"Is there a more appropriate method?"

I did answer the question.
My answer is that I feel there is a more appropriate method.
The svn_wc ruby gem further simplfies using the ruby SVN bindings.
The code I provided will print the commit date of every entry in 'HEAD'.

I apologize if this was not what you are looking for but to be down voted for providing what seems to be a valid answer based on your question does not seem appropriate.